# PHP Mail script not working when header are added

Tags: php, email

So I have a email form that takes a name, email, and message. The problem is I am not receiving anything through email and Im not sure why.

Here is the code

```
 $headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "$email";
$headers[] = "Reply-To: $email";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
        mail($myemail, "Portfolio Email From $name", $mess, $headers);
        $errorshere = "Message Sent";
        header("Location: index.php?errors=".$errorshere."#contactpage");
```

Comment: It's this line `$headers[] = "$email";` You're probably missing a `From:` and is breaking your header.

Comment: I added "From:" to that but still not coming through.

Comment: $headers is getting put into an array, I see no header array output.  See example 2: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php